# Why is NASM assembly 64 bit printf not printing value of floating point division?

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm, x86-64

My goal here is to add 3 floating point numbers and divide by 3 to calculate the average and then print the result.

While it assembles and executes, I am getting : 
The average of the numbers is 0.000000

rather than the calculated average.

Can someone please tell me why it is displaying 0.000000 instead of the average?

```
%macro EXITPGM 0
mov eax, 0
call exit
%endmacro

section .data
flt1  dq 0.0

msg db "The average of the numbers is %f",10,0


section .text
global main
extern printf
extern exit

main:
    push rbp
    mov dword [flt1], __float64__(3.93)
    mov rsi, __float64__(9.4)
    mov rdx, __float64__(84.52)
    add rsi, [flt1]
    add rsi, rdx
    mov rdx, 0
    mov rax, rsi
    mov rcx, 3
    div rcx
    mov rdi, msg
    mov rax, 1
    movq xmm0, rax
    call printf

    pop rbp
    EXITPGM
```

Comment: You are doing integer additions and divisions on floating point numbers.  What do you exactly expect to happen?

Comment: Use `addsd` and `divsd` for double-precision FP addition / division on x86-64.  Look at compiler output for a C function.    Also, `mov dword [flt1], __float64__(3.93)` only sets the low dword of the qword `double`.  (i.e. the low 32 bits of the significand, leaving the exponent 0 so this is a very tiny subnormal number.)

Comment: Not to mention that `mov rax, 1` will overwrite whatever wrong result you have calculated :)